# Show that the set with the following operation and group product is a group. Allan Clark Elements of Abstract Algebra question 28(delta)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working through some group theory texts and am stuck on the following problem.

> Let $S$ be a set with an operation which assigns to each ordered pair
>   $(a,b)$ of elements of $S$ an element $a/b$ of $S$ in such a way that:
>
> (1) there is an element $1 \in S$ such that $a/b=1$ if and only if $a=b$;
>
> (2) for any elements $a,b,c \in S$, $(a/c)/(b/c)=a/b$.
>
> Show that $S$ is a group under the product defined by $ab=a/(1/b)$.

My attempt to show that $1(=1/1)$ is the identity:

$$a\cdot 1/1=a/(1/(1/1))=a/(1/1)=a/1$$

However I am not sure how to show that $a/1=a$ .
I was thinking about trying to use property (2) to show that $a/(a \cdot 1)=1$  but this did not prove fruitful.

My attempt to show that $1/a = a^{-1}$ :
$$a\cdot(1/a)=a/(1/(1/a))=a/((a/a)/(1/a))=a/(a/1) $$
Then using the working above I know $a\cdot 1=a/1$

Thus $a\cdot (1/a)=a/(a\cdot 1) $

But again am not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$1/(b/a)=(a/a)/(b/a)=a/b$$
Suppose
$$a/b=a/c$$
Then
$$b/a=c/a$$
Then
$$(b/a)/(c/a)=b/c=1$$
Hence
$$b=c$$
Now
$$1/(a/1)=1/a$$
So
$$a/1=a$$

Comment: I was wondering how you "knew" to do this, had you seen a similar problem or were you able to just work it out? Do you remember any of your thought process? Having now seen the answer it seems clear but I don't know how I would have ever thought to do this myself. Thanks.

Comment: @fourier1234 I don't know if you saw my earlier comment, I wasn't convinced it was possible for a little bit. It's true that I'm a bit predisposed to being able to solve  this sort of problem because I was planning to do something similar for my dissertation (abstract axioms for something algebraic that are not at all obviously equivalent to the usual ones) but I believe somewhere along the way here I remembered that multiplying by a group element is a bijective function, so I thought maybe it would help to see that the same is true of this operation.